# How to convert single image to video in infinite loop and set duration of 15 seconds using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Can anyone help me with a command line for the below scenario please using FFmpeg?

Convert single `image.jpg` to `output.mp4` for 15 seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/cartoon-weather-images-16836392.jpg -t 15 output.mp4
```

FFprobe result:

> ```
> ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg  
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':   Metadata:  
>     major_brand     : isom  
>     minor_version   : 512  
>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
>     encoder         : Lavf57.83.100   Duration: 00:00:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 188 kb/s  
>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1182x1300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 591:650], 186 kb/s, 25 fps, 25  
> tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)  
>     Metadata:  
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
> ```

Comment: Thank you @xer-rex. I used `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 15  video.mp4`